# Move children Image() objects along with the parent object

Tags: kivy

i add Image() objects to a parent Widget() with parent_widget.add_widget(Image()).
Image objects have a image texture which works ok. But the issue is that I would like them all to move when I move the parent Widget.

Is there an easy solution for this? For now I have ended up looping through all child objects of the parent and repositioning them with offset values.

I use no kv file, purely Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [layout class](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html) instead of a Widget, this is the point of them. For instance, if you want them stacked horizontally and vertically to fill the available space you could use a BoxLayout.